# AutoHotkey Script Support Request to lock CapsLock Key in the "On" position

Tags: autohotkey

Request for Support:
I modified the following AutoHotkey script (found within the forum) to set the CapsLock Key to the "On" position for a db table (PhD research project) that I am working on.  The CapsLock key is disabled in the "On" position using this script, which is desirable; however, no matter how long the CapsLock Key is depressed (I am using Win7), the script functionality is not broken and I must exit AutoHotkey to return the CapsLock Key to a normal on-off toggle state.

I would appreciate any suggested modifications re the script below with regard to breaking the script "ON" loop if the CapsLock key is depressed from more than a few seconds.  I am a new new forum user/novice programmer and while I am sure that the scripting solution is a simple matter, I am at a loss as to how best to modify the script code further to accomplish the program break sequence.  Advice or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
;Disable modified Caps Lock Key Script
*CapsLock::Return
;Hold Caps Lock for approximately 1 second to enable, tap to disable
CapsLock::
{
SetCapsLockState, On
Return
}
Count=0
While GetKeyState("CapsLock", "P")
{
Count++
Sleep, 1
If Count > 5
{
Send, {CapsLock}
Break
}
}
KeyWait, CapsLock
Return
```

Comment: please mark one of the answers as correct.  It just helps keep things organized :-)

Answer (score 2):

This script enables CapsLock if held for more than a second and turns it off with any press after that.

```
CapsLock::
    KeyWait, CapsLock
    GetKeyState, state, CapsLock, T
    If (A_TimeSinceThisHotkey >= 1000) and !(state = "D")
        SetCapsLockState, On
    Else
        SetCapsLockState, Off
Return
```

Comment: Grey, Elliot;
Many thanks to both of you for your assistance with this script.  Grey; your version is actually on target with my intent but Elliot; your version is helpful as the reverse of my intent as there are other scenarios when lowercase is preferred and I accidentally hit the CapsLock key by mistake.  In sort, problem solved and I am back on track with my research work.  Many, many thanks for your assistance with this!
Ernie

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the best option would be for you toggle state of this key after its released? For example:

```
SetStoreCapslockMode, Off
CapsLock::
   KeyWait, CapsLock
   If A_TimeSinceThisHotkey>=1000 ; check an condition here
      Send, {CapsLock}
   Return
```

Comment: Grey, Elliot;
Many thanks to both of you for your assistance with this script.  Grey; your version is actually on target with my intent but Elliot; your version is helpful as the reverse of my intent as there are other scenarios when lowercase is preferred and I accidentally hit the CapsLock key by mistake.  In sort, problem solved and I am back on track with my research work.  Many, many thanks for your assistance with this!
Ernie

Comment: Hi Grey,  I'm not sure why this works, but this modification of your script works perfectly to toggle the fixed on-off CapsLock key feature (avoiding problems created by repeated use of tab key and accidentally hitting the CapsLock key) but the sequence is Ctrl _ CapsLock to toggle on-off.  Pressing the CapsLock key alone has no effect.  The modification is shown below:

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why (can you enlighten?), but this modification works perfectly, but the toggle sequence is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to toggle on-off.

;This script enables <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to be locked in the on or off position.  Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to control whether the lock is enabled for uppercase or lower case.  Pressing the <kbd>CapLock</kbd> key alone has no effect when extensive use of the Tab key is underway.

```
CapsLock::
    KeyWait, CapsLock
    GetKeyState, state, CapsLock, T
    If (A_TimeSinceThisHotkey >= 5) and !(state = "D")
        SetCapsLockState, Off
    Else
        SetCapsLockState, on
Return
```